# Passing a state for an Axios POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I want to pass a state into an axios post request, for the state data to get into my backend. But i get an error telling me the state that i chose is not defined.

Here's what i've got:

React frontend

```jsx
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

class Gluecksrad extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      spieler: "",
    };
  }

  submitName() {
    const body = { spieler: this.state.spieler };
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert", body).then(() => {
      console.log(this.state.spieler);
      alert("successful insert");
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Glücksrad</h1>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.setState({ spieler: e.target.value });
            console.log(this.state.spieler);
          }}
        ></input>
        <button onClick={this.submitName}>Name Absenden</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Gluecksrad;
```

Node Backend

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/api/insert", (req, res) => {
  const spieler = req.body.spieler;

  const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO spiele (spieler) VALUES (?)";
  db.query(sqlInsert, spieler, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Here is the result

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfYmD.png)

Comment: I think what you need is `onClick={this.submitName.bind(this)}`. There's a duplicate around here somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

In your function `submitName` you are creating the body of the axios request using a variable `spieler` but it has not been defined previously. You should make use of `spieler` from state as follows:

```js
submitName() {
  const body = { spieler: this.state.spieler };
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert", body).then(() => {
    console.log(this.state.spieler);
    alert("successful insert");
  });
}
```

Regarding your second problem of `this.state` being `undefined`, this results from the fact that by default, you can't access the surrounding context represented by the `this` keyword when using regular functions because they have their own context. Since you are indeed using a regular function `submitName()`, you need to bind `this` to it in order to access the context of the surrounding class. Alternatively, you can make use of an arrow function `submitName = () => {}` which doesn't need binding as it preserves the surrounding context. I've created this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fast-g3kqbf) for you which shows the two valid options as well as the wrong approach. Mind the `console.log(this)`. It logs the `Gluecksrad` class for the arrow function or regular function with `this` binding while it logs `undefined` when submitting without `this` binding. Accessing the `state` property with `this` being `undefined` in the latter approach is the root of the error. You can read more about the reason for `this` binding in this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/this-binding-in-es6-arrow-function-70d80e216238).

Comment: After trying this it says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')"

Comment: Is your state defined in the constructor? Please add more of your code.

Comment: Yes, i will provide the Code of the whole class then.

Comment: @Kiri I've edited my answer and added an extensive explanation to your second problem. You should be able to get it running now and understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your methode `submitName` by adding this line to your constructor.  [you can learn more about react forms from the official docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

```
this.submitName = this.submitName.bind(this);
```

you constructorshould look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        spieler: "",
    };
    this.submitName = this.submitName.bind(this);
}
```

You are not accessing the real properties.
replace

```
{
      spieler: spieler,
}
```

with

```
{
      spieler: this.state.spieler,
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I updated the solution try it now..